# using autopostback on dropdownlist that also has submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, drop-down-menu

Have a dropdown list with autopostback set to 'yes' have another dropdown list box that will be populated based on the selection of the first dropdown.  It works fine until I put a submit botton on the form.  When I do it appears to not do the auto postback until the submit button is pushed.  Can you have a submit button on a form that has a dropdown with autopostback active.  thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

Are you handling the autopostback event of the first dropdown in the code-behind file to populate the second dropdown? If so, your postback event should be firing when you change your selection in the first dropdown. Put a breakpoint in your code to assure that your event code is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Are you seeing it not load the second dropdown? If so, check where you're handling that, as it may be in the wrong spot (if you're doing it with code) or you might have it wrapped in a !postback without thinking about it. Post more code and explanation for more help.

Comment: I would be glad to add code... new to this fourm, how do I add code. Inside these comment boxes?